# Creating EC2 instances in multiple subnets with Terraform using for each

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, terraform, subnet

I currently have multiple subnets created within a VPC for each availability zone within a region. I am now trying to create one EC2 instance per subnet within each availability zone, and am running into an issue. Below is my code, I am having some trouble getting the subnet ID to attach to EC2 instances. Any advice would be appreciated.

**Instance**

```
resource "aws_instance" "public" {
  for_each      = aws_subnet.public
  ami           = data.aws_ami.ec2.id
  instance_type = var.tableau_instance
  key_name      = aws_key_pair.main.key_name
  subnet_id     = [for subnet in aws_subnet.public : subnet.id]
}
```

**Subnet**

```
locals {
  az_names = data.aws_availability_zones.azs.names
}

resource "aws_subnet" "public" {
  for_each                = { for index, az_name in local.az_names : index => az_name }
  vpc_id                  = aws_vpc.main.id
  cidr_block              = cidrsubnet(var.vpc_cidr, 8, each.key + 1)
  availability_zone       = local.az_names[each.key]
  map_public_ip_on_launch = true
  tags = {
    Name = "${var.vpc_tags}_PubSubnet"
  }
}
```

**Error**

```
Error: Incorrect attribute value type

  on vpc.tf line 18, in resource "aws_instance" "public":
  18:   subnet_id     = [for subnet in aws_subnet.public : subnet.id]
    |----------------
    | aws_subnet.public is object with 3 attributes

Inappropriate value for attribute "subnet_id": string required.
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The instance code should be as follows:

```
resource "aws_instance" "public" {
  for_each      = aws_subnet.public
  ami           = data.aws_ami.ec2.id
  instance_type = var.tableau_instance
  key_name      = aws_key_pair.main.key_name
  subnet_id     = each.value.id
}
```

This will place 1 instance in each subnet.